# Call a function whenever an Attribute's value is changed in Maximo 7.5

Tags: java, maximo

Is it possible to call a java function or an automation script whenever an attribute's value is changed. No matter if the value is changed from GUI or directly in DB (bypassing Maximo)?

Answer (score 1):

Maximo does offer [eAuditing function.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/audit_tracking_in_maximo8?lang=en)

I am not sure how you expect an application to keep track of direct database changes since the application is not involved in the change. Changes in the GUI can be tracked using the eAudit functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can call the script or a Java function when the value is changed via the application - there is no way to do it, if it is changed directly in the database - at least not immediately when the field is changed. The only way to do this would be to have two fields, i.e. FIELD1 and FIELD1OLD, and to have an escalation that would check the content of these fields. Whenever FIELD1's value would be changed (for example via database), the contend of both fields would be different. Your custom Java code would the write the content of FIELD1 to FIELD1OLD, and at the same time execute your custom code.

Might not be a great way to do it, but is the only way, if you want to change the content of the field directly in the database.